# Where is the MoveIt python interface installed?

Tags: catkin, moveit

I have built Moveit from source on Ubuntu 20.04 and want to use the python-based move group interface.

I'm not too familiar with the syntax of `cmake` therefore I don't know where the python-based move group interface is installed.

Identifying from `CMakeList.txt`, I think the python interface is installed to `${CATKIN_PACKAGE_PYTHON_DESTINATION}` which is shown in [this line](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/1730d7b392a072bafaab37e6e3bb8ed11e58047e/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/CMakeLists.txt#L13).

I have created a minimal example with

```
message(STATUS "devel path: ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}")
message(STATUS "python destination: ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_PYTHON_DESTINATION}")
```

where I got the devel path output in the terminal but `${CATKIN_PACKAGE_PYTHON_DESTINATION}` is empty after `catkin build --verbose`.

What path does `${CATKIN_PACKAGE_PYTHON_DESTINATION}` specifically represent？

Is the installation path of the python interface for move group related to this variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

> Where is the MoveIt python interface installed?

You can use the following commands to see the installation location of a Python package:

1. `<package>.__path__` lets you identify the location(s) of a specific package
2. `<module>.__file__` lets you identify the location of a specific module

Please see a complete demonstration below:

```
$ cd ~/ws_moveit
$ source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
$ source ~/ws_moveit/devel/setup.bash
$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, May 26 2023, 14:05:08) 

>>> import moveit_commander
>>> moveit_commander.__file__
'/home/test/ws_moveit/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages/moveit_commander/__init__.py'

>>> moveit_commander.__path__
['/home/test/ws_moveit/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages/moveit_commander', '/home/test/ws_moveit/src/moveit/moveit_commander/src/moveit_commander']
```

In the above example, you can notice that MoveIt is installed at the `~/ws_moveit/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages/moveit_commander/` location because it was built from source as per your question.

Source: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46071447/)

Comment: Thanks! @ravi I have tried your answer but I'm still confused about the value of `${CATKIN_PACKAGE_PYTHON_DESTINATION}`. I've searched online but didn't find a detailed explanation about this variable. I get an empty value when `catkin build --verbose`. Do you know why? Thanks!